# How to replace a number as an image in Xcode 5

Tags: ios, xcode, string, image

I am kinda new to Xcode and I am making a program. What I would like to do is when a person gets a score, it will output it on the screen. Example, the person got a score of 132, it would show the score as "132", how would I replace the numbers with an image so instead of using a font, the numbers are showing as an image. I was thinking if there is anyway to use something like this to output the numbers as a picture, but this wouldn't put them in order or it wouldn't work anyway. If anyone can help me, i'd really appreciate it. Thanks!

```
one   = [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"]; //Image for the number 1
two   = [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"]; //Image for the number 2
three = [UIImage imageNamed:@"3.png"]; //Image for the number 3

NSString *score = "132"; //This is the score the user got

if ([score rangeOfString:@"1"].location == NSFound) {
    imagescore = one; //If the score contains one, the image adds the image 1
}
if ([score rangeOfString:@"2"].location == NSFound) {
    imagescore += two; //If the score contains two, the image adds the image 2
}
if ([score rangeOfString:@"3"].location == NSFound) {
    imagescore +=three; //If the score contains two, the image adds the image 3
}
imageView.image = imagescore; //Would change the image to the images of the score in order
```

Comment: For that, u have to store all the images containing one to infinity numbers :P

Comment: Can't you have like `imagescore = one + three + two;` to put the images together?

Comment: Simply make a view with custom background(with image) and place a `UILabel` above it. This could save your time and space both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here i made an array of UIImage from your *score* string:

EDIT: Now i commented out the array making parts and included [iMani](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22220407/1293167)'s solution to merge the images together. Is it now clear?

```
-(void)calculateScore{
    NSString *score = @"132";

    UIImage *scroreImage = [UIImage new];
   // NSMutableArray *images = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:score.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < score.length; i++) {
       // imageName will be @"1", then @"3" and @"2"
        NSString *imageName = [[score substringToIndex:i] substringToIndex:1];

       // add extension
       imageName = [imageName stringByAppendingString:@".png"];

       UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];

       //[images addObject:image];
       scroreImage = [self concateImageOne:scroreImage withImageTwo:image]
    }
}

-(UIImage*)concateImageOne:(UIImage*)image1 withImageTwo:(UIImage*)image2
{
     ///Merge images together
}
```

[concateImageOne:withImageTwo: selector made by iMani](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22220407/1293167)

Comment: If the images are in a sub-directory, let's say /numbers, would I have to add anything for the directory, or just have it normal

Comment: You don't to name the folder where it is if its not in a .bundle directory.

Comment: I have tried doing something like this `UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, imagescore.size.width, imagescore.size.height)];
imageView.image = images;` to show the images, but I get an error doing it, how would I show the images on the storyboard?

Comment: now i tried to make it clearer and instead of making an array, i used iMani's solution to merge the images, now you can use it like: `imageView.image = scoreImage`

Answer (score 1):

I can understand little bit. You have number image like `1.png.,2.png,3.png`. If score is `132`, you want to show image as `1.png + 2.png + 3.png`. That want **merge** this image into one image.

Code for Merge two images..

```
-(UIImage*)concateImageOne:(UIImage*)image1 withImageTwo:(UIImage*)image2
{
  CGSize size = CGSizeMake(image1.size.width, image1.size.height + image2.size.height);
  UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);

  [image1 drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,size.width, image1.size.height)];
  [image2 drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,image1.size.height,size.width, image2.size.height)];

  UIImage *finalImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

  UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
  return finalImage;
}
```

Now check with condition, and merge images.

```
if ([score rangeOfString:@"1"].location == NSFound) {
    if (!imagescore)
        imagescore = one; //If the score contains one, the image adds the image 1
    else 
        imagescore = [self concateImageOne:imagescore withImageTwo:one]
}
```

As like, merge all image with condition. Finally, recreate imageview and assign image as below.

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, imagescore.size.width, imagescore.size.height)];
imageView.image = imagescore;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get list of Image by follow code:

```
- (NSArray *)imageFromString:(NSString *)scoreString
{
    NSMutableArray *scoreImages = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (int i = 0; i < scoreString.length; i++) {
        NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c.png", [scoreString characterAtIndex:i]];
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
        [scoreImages addObject:image];
    }
    return scoreImages;
}
```

and write a function to show this list image to view

Answer (score 0):

What I did was:

```
-(void)calculateScore {
    int hundred = self.score / 100;
    int ten = self.score / 10;
    int remainder = self.score % 10;

    NSString *hundredString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"number_%d.png", hundred];
    NSString *tenString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"number_%d.png", ten];
    NSString *remainderString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"number_%d.png", remainder];

    self.hundredImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:hundredString];
    self.tenImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:tenString];
    self.remainderImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:remainderString];
}
```